# DiscordPy Disable Command: Command Which Disable A Specific Command In A Specific Server

Tags: python, command, discord

Hi This Is My First Question On StackOverflow lol.
I want to make a command which disables a specific command in a specific server and it would be like:- **!disable ping** si this will disable ping command in the server. I also want the bot to send **Command {command} Is Disabled in {guild}** So let me send you a starter-

```
@bot.command
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def disable(ctx, command)
command = ...
```

Just something like this, sorry I am asking for full code I hope you it's clear to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a dictionary for each server may be one of the most straightforward methods. With this method, you'll simply need to add 3 lines of code before each command to check that it's enabled. Please note that this example doesn't include storing the data and doesn't account for more commands needing to be added to commandsEnabled dictionary.

```
commandsEnabled = {}

@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    commandsEnabled[str(guild.id)] = {}
    for cmd in bot.commands:
        commandsEnabled[str(guild.id)][cmd.name] = True
    
@bot.command
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def Toggle(ctx, command):
    try:
        commandsEnabled[str(guild.id)][cmd.name] = not commandsEnabled[str(guild.id)][cmd.name]
        await ctx.send(f"{command} command {['disabled','enabled'][int()]}")
    except KeyError:
        await ctx.send(":x:Command with that name not found")

@bot.command
async def Example(ctx):
    if not commandsEnabled[str(ctx.guild.id)]["Example"]:
        await ctx.send(":x:This command has been disabled")
        return
    await ctx.send("Hello world!")
```